# The footer and the header kept repeating themselves in the body (contentType="application/msword")

Tags: css, html, visualforce, ms-word

this is more to share knowledge, I'm having to generate a .doc document from a vfp, and I had some problems with the footer/header, one of the problems was that both the footer and the header kept repeating themselves in the body of the document, I saw that many people had the same problem and no solution, so I came to share the solution that worked for me:

Comment: Thank you for your contribution. Please take a moment to read about [ask], [answer], and [Can I answer my own question?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer). You can edit your question and answer to meet our guidelines. Your question should not contain the answer, and your answer should not just be code.

Comment: Thanks for your tip, I made the changes @sfdcfox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The table+id='hrdftrtbl' tag makes the header/footer not repeat at the end of the doc

```html
<table id="hrdftrtbl"><!--The table+id='hrdftrtbl' tag makes the header/footer not repeat at the end of the doc-->
Footer or Header
</table>
```